# Ganache gives error when I try to mint token to wallet after contract deploy

Tags: solidity, python, ganache-cli, docker

**i use**: python 3.5, docker, ganache (image image: trufflesuite/ganache-cli:v6.9.1)

**what do i do**: (*simplified example*) I have two container: container with ganache and container with general logic. Ganache container started fine. Then in second container i launched two scripts which deploy contracts and then mint tokens to wallet. Deploy was done successful but on mint step i get ganache error. I tried various solutions, but the problem repeats over and over again. (it's all need for the local environment tests and i use case without truffele, ganache only)

**my code**:
*docker-compose.yaml:*

```
  ganache:
    image: trufflesuite/ganache-cli:v6.9.1
    command: >
      --seed test
      --account="my_wallet_1,1000000000000000000000"
      --account="my_wallet_2,1000000000000000000000"
      --account="my_wallet_3,1000000000000000000000000"
    ports:
      - "8545:8545"

  my_second_container:
    build: <build_mane>
    entrypoint: "<script_for_parse_secret_env_variables>.sh"
    command: "<script_for_deploy_contract_and_mint_tokens>.sh"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - <volumes_for_logs_scripts_etc.>
    depends_on:
      - db
      - ganache
    environment: 
      <NAME_ENV_VARIABLE>: <VALUE>
      CONTRACTS_PATH: ./contracts
      WEB3_RPC_URL: http://ganache:8545
```

*deploy_contract.py:*

```
import os
import json

from time import sleep
from web3 import Account, HTTPProvider, Web3
from pprint import pprint


node_url = os.environ['WEB3_RPC_URL']
w3 = Web3(HTTPProvider(node_url))

ARTIFACTS_PATH = './contracts/'

if 'CONTRACTS_PATH' in os.environ:
    ARTIFACTS_PATH = os.environ['CONTRACTS_PATH']

if not os.path.isdir(ARTIFACTS_PATH):
    raise Exception('No contracts directory found')

TOKEN_NAME = 'MyToken'
CROWDSALE_NAME = 'Crowdsale'

# Wait for ganache up
tries = 100
while tries > 0:
    if w3.isConnected():
        break
    tries = tries - 1
    sleep(1)

if tries == 0:
    raise Exception('No test net')

w3.eth.defaultAccount = w3.eth.accounts[0]

backend_address = Account.privateKeyToAccount(os.environ['BACKEND_PRIVATE_KEY']).address
if w3.eth.defaultAccount != backend_address:
    print('default:', w3.eth.defaultAccount)
    raise Exception('Wrong default account')
else:
    CORP_WALLET = backend_address
    print('CORPORATION WALLET :  %s' % w3.eth.defaultAccount)


#  --- MYTOKEN token deploy  ---

with open(os.path.join(ARTIFACTS_PATH, TOKEN_NAME + '.json')) as file:
    token_interface = json.loads(file.read())

TokenMY = w3.eth.contract(abi=token_interface['abi'], bytecode=token_interface['bytecode'])
tx_hash = TokenMY.constructor().transact()
tx_receipt = w3.eth.waitForTransactionReceipt(tx_hash)
token_address = tx_receipt.contractAddress
print('MYTOKEN contracts successfully deployed')
print('MYTOKEN token address :  %s' % token_address)


#  --- CROWDS deploy  ---

with open(os.path.join(ARTIFACTS_PATH, CROWDSALE_NAME + '.json')) as file:
    crowdsale_interface = json.loads(file.read())
Crowdsale = w3.eth.contract(abi=crowdsale_interface['abi'], bytecode=crowdsale_interface['bytecode'])
tx_hash = Crowdsale.constructor(token_address, backend_address).transact()
tx_receipt = w3.eth.waitForTransactionReceipt(tx_hash)
crowdsale_address = tx_receipt.contractAddress

token = w3.eth.contract(address=token_address, abi=token_interface['abi'])
crowdsale = w3.eth.contract(address=crowdsale_address, abi=crowdsale_interface['abi'])

tx_hash = token.functions.transferOwnership(crowdsale_address).transact()
tx_receipt = w3.eth.waitForTransactionReceipt(tx_hash)
tx_hash = crowdsale.functions.claimTokenOwnership().transact()
tx_receipt = w3.eth.waitForTransactionReceipt(tx_hash)
print('CROWD SALE contract successfully deployed')
print('CROWD SALE address :  %s' % crowdsale_address)


#  -- save addresses to json file --

addresses = {
    TOKEN_NAME: token_address,
    CROWDSALE_NAME: crowdsale_address
}

with open(os.path.join(ARTIFACTS_PATH, 'Addresses.json'), 'w') as file:
    file.write(json.dumps(addresses))

print('Contract addresses saved to Addresses.json file')

print('==========addresses in deploy=============')
pprint(addresses)
print('=======================')
```

*mint_tokens.py:*

```
import json
import os

from pprint import pprint
from web3 import HTTPProvider, Web3


NODE_URL = os.environ['WEB3_RPC_URL']
w3 = Web3(HTTPProvider(NODE_URL))
TOKEN_NAME = 'MyToken'
CORP_WALLET = os.environ['BACKEND_WALLET']
ARTIFACTS_PATH = os.environ['CONTRACTS_PATH']
MYTOKEN_TOKENS_TO_MINT = 3000 * 10 ** 8

if not os.path.isdir(ARTIFACTS_PATH):
    raise Exception('No contracts directory found')

with open(os.path.join(ARTIFACTS_PATH, TOKEN_NAME + '.json')) as file:
    token_interface = json.loads(file.read())

with open(os.path.join(ARTIFACTS_PATH, 'Addresses.json'), 'r') as addr_file:
    addresses = json.loads(addr_file.read())

print('==========addresses in mint=============')
pprint(addresses)
print('=======================')

mytoken_contract = w3.eth.contract(abi=token_interface['abi'], address=addresses[TOKEN_NAME])
tx_hash = mytoken_contract.functions.mint(CORP_WALLET, MYTOKEN_TOKENS_TO_MINT).transact()
result = w3.eth.waitForTransactionReceipt(tx_hash)

balance = mytoken_contract.functions.balanceOf(CORP_WALLET).call()
print('To wallet %s was been charged %s MYTOKEN tokens' % (CORP_WALLET, balance))

print('MYTOKEN mint was SUCCESS !')
```

*print returns:*

```
==========addresses in deploy=============
{'Crowdsale': '0xe64dd1036374B5CDB1D639205e291BAC5bA0BF59',
 'MyToken': '0x6efD7f1cC59436Ca14dE520FCC5D491238C6e6dD'}
=======================

==========addresses in mint=============
{'Crowdsale': '0xe64dd1036374B5CDB1D639205e291BAC5bA0BF59',
 'MyToken': '0x6efD7f1cC59436Ca14dE520FCC5D491238C6e6dD'}
=======================
```

*dir(mytoken_contract.functions) returns:*

```
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattr__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_functions', 'abi', 'allowance', 'approve', 'balanceOf', 'burn', 'burnFrom', 'claimOwnership', 'decimals', 'decreaseAllowance', 'increaseAllowance', 'mint', 'name', 'owner', 'pendingOwner', 'symbol', 'totalSupply', 'transfer', 'transferFrom', 'transferOwnership']
```

*MyToken.sol*

```
pragma solidity 0.5.10;

import "./Claimable.sol";
import "../openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "../openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20Burnable.sol";


contract MyToken is ERC20, ERC20Burnable, Claimable {
    string public name = "Public Name Token";
    string public symbol = "PNT";
    uint8 public decimals = 8;

    /**
     * @dev Function to mint tokens
     * @param to The address that will receive the minted tokens.
     * @param value The amount of tokens to mint.
     * @return A boolean that indicates if the operation was successful.
     */
    function mint(address to, uint256 value) public onlyOwner returns (bool) {
        require(value > 0);
        _mint(to, value);
        return true;
    }
}
```

*Claimable.sol*

```
pragma solidity 0.5.10;

/**
 * @title Claimable
 * @dev Claimable contract, where the ownership needs to be claimed.
 * This allows the new owner to accept the transfer.
 */
contract Claimable {
    address public owner;
    address public pendingOwner;

    event OwnershipTransferred(
        address indexed previousOwner,
        address indexed newOwner
    );

    /**
    * @dev The Claimable constructor sets the original `owner` of the contract to the sender
    * account.
    */
    constructor() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    /**
    * @dev Throws if called by any account other than the owner.
    */
    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

    /**
    * @dev Modifier throws if called by any account other than the pendingOwner.
    */
    modifier onlyPendingOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == pendingOwner);
        _;
    }

    /**
    * @dev Allows the current owner to set the pendingOwner address.
    * @param newOwner The address to transfer ownership to.
    */
    function transferOwnership(address newOwner) public onlyOwner {
        pendingOwner = newOwner;
    }

    /**
    * @dev Allows the pendingOwner address to finalize the transfer.
    */
    function claimOwnership() public onlyPendingOwner {
        emit OwnershipTransferred(owner, pendingOwner);
        owner = pendingOwner;
        pendingOwner = address(0);
    }
}
```

*error:*

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 31, in <module>
    main()
  File "./manage.py", line 27, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/shell.py", line 92, in handle
    exec(sys.stdin.read())
  File "<string>", line 49, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/web3/contract.py", line 1151, in transact
    **self.kwargs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/web3/contract.py", line 1454, in transact_with_contract_function
    txn_hash = web3.eth.sendTransaction(transact_transaction)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/web3/eth.py", line 264, in sendTransaction
    get_buffered_gas_estimate(self.web3, transaction),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/web3/utils/transactions.py", line 84, in get_buffered_gas_estimate
    gas_estimate = web3.eth.estimateGas(gas_estimate_transaction)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/web3/eth.py", line 305, in estimateGas
    [transaction],
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/web3/manager.py", line 112, in request_blocking
    raise ValueError(response["error"])
ValueError: {'message': 'VM Exception while processing transaction: revert', 'code': -32000, 'data': {'stack': 'c: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert\n    at Function.c.fromResults (/app/ganache-core.docker.cli.js:2:257479)\n    at e.exports (/app/ganache-core.docker.cli.js:53:1406305)', 'name': 'c'}}
```

Comment: Problem in token contract i guess, becauce 'bytecode' for this token was created for owner and it's not test address that i use locally, so i need to create a new 'bytecode' data with my test address and then to deploy it in ganache. If it will be right way i explain in detail in the answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrote deploy_contract.py and mint_tokens.py scripts.

*deploy_contract.py*:

```
import json
import os
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime as dt, timedelta as td

from web3 import Account, HTTPProvider, Web3

node_url = os.environ['WEB3_RPC_URL']

ARTIFACTS_PATH = './contracts/'

if 'CONTRACTS_PATH' in os.environ:
    ARTIFACTS_PATH = os.environ['CONTRACTS_PATH']

if not os.path.isdir(ARTIFACTS_PATH):
    raise Exception('No contracts directory found')

TOKEN_NAME = 'MyToken'
KEEPER_NAME = 'Keeper'
DAI_NAME = 'DAI'

w3 = Web3(HTTPProvider(node_url))

# Wait for ganache up
tries = 100
while tries > 0:
    if w3.isConnected():
        break
    tries = tries - 1
    sleep(1)

if tries == 0:
    raise Exception('No test net')

w3.eth.defaultAccount = w3.eth.accounts[0]

backend_address = Account.privateKeyToAccount(os.environ['BACKEND_PRIVATE_KEY']).address
w3.eth.defaultAccount = backend_address
print('Default Account address:  %s' % backend_address)


#  ----------- Deploy MY Token -------------------

print('Deploy MY Token')
with open(os.path.join(ARTIFACTS_PATH, TOKEN_NAME + '.json')) as file:
    token_interface = json.loads(file.read())

Token = w3.eth.contract(abi=token_interface['abi'], bytecode=token_interface['bytecode'])
tx_hash = Token.constructor().transact()
tx_receipt = w3.eth.waitForTransactionReceipt(tx_hash)
token_address = tx_receipt.contractAddress
print('MY Token address: %s' % token_address)
print('Deploy MY Token was successful')


#  ----------- Deploy KEEPER -------------------

print('Deploy KEEPER')
with open(os.path.join(ARTIFACTS_PATH, KEEPER_NAME + '.json')) as file:
    keeper_interface = json.loads(file.read())

Keeper = w3.eth.contract(abi=keeper_interface['abi'], bytecode=keeper_interface['bytecode'])

dt1 = dt.now() + td(days=1)
dt2 = dt1 + td(days=365)

tx_hash = Keeper.constructor(token_address, int(dt1.timestamp()), int(dt2.timestamp())).transact()
tx_receipt = w3.eth.waitForTransactionReceipt(tx_hash)
keeper_address = tx_receipt.contractAddress
print('KEEPER address: %s' % keeper_address)
print('Deploy KEEPER was successful')


#  ----------- Deploy DAI Token -------------------

print('Deploy DAI Token')
with open(os.path.join(ARTIFACTS_PATH, DAI_NAME + '.json')) as f:
    dai_interface = json.loads(f.read())

DAI = w3.eth.contract(abi=dai_interface['abi'], bytecode=dai_interface['bytecode'])
tx_hash = DAI.constructor().transact()
tx_receipt = w3.eth.waitForTransactionReceipt(tx_hash)
dai_address = tx_receipt.contractAddress
print('DAI Token address: %s' % dai_address)
print('Deploy DAI Token was successful')


#  ----------- Create file with contracts addresses -------------------

file_name = 'Addresses.json'
print('Create file %s with contracts addresses' % file_name)

addresses = {
    TOKEN_NAME: token_address,
    KEEPER_NAME: keeper_address,
    DAI_NAME: dai_address,
}

with open(os.path.join(ARTIFACTS_PATH, file_name), 'w') as file:
    file.write(json.dumps(addresses))

print('File %s with contracts addresses was created' % token_address)
print('Deploy was completed successful')
```

*mint_tokens.py*:

```
import json
import os

from time import sleep
from web3 import Account, HTTPProvider, Web3


ARTIFACTS_PATH = './contracts/'

if 'CONTRACTS_PATH' in os.environ:
    ARTIFACTS_PATH = os.environ['CONTRACTS_PATH']

if not os.path.isdir(ARTIFACTS_PATH):
    raise Exception('No contracts directory found')

TOKEN_NAME = 'MyToken'
KEEPER_NAME = 'Keeper'
DAI_NAME = 'DAI'
node_url = os.environ['WEB3_RPC_URL']
w3 = Web3(HTTPProvider(node_url))

# Wait for ganache up
tries = 100
while tries > 0:
    if w3.isConnected():
        break
    tries = tries - 1
    sleep(1)

if tries == 0:
    raise Exception('No test net')

if int(w3.version.network) < 5:
    print('network_id not ganache')
    print(w3.version.network)
    exit(1)

backend_address = Account.privateKeyToAccount(os.environ['BACKEND_PRIVATE_KEY']).address
w3.eth.defaultAccount = backend_address
print('Default Account address:  %s' % backend_address)

with open(os.path.join(ARTIFACTS_PATH, 'Addresses.json'), 'r') as addr_file:
    addresses = json.loads(addr_file.read())


#  ----------- Mint DAI Token -------------------

print('Mint DAI Token')
DAI_TOKENS_TO_MINT = 1000 * 10 ** 18

with open(os.path.join(ARTIFACTS_PATH, DAI_NAME + '.json')) as f:
    dai_interface = json.loads(f.read())

DAI = w3.eth.contract(abi=dai_interface['abi'], address=addresses[DAI_NAME])
tx_hash_dai = DAI.functions.mint(backend_address, DAI_TOKENS_TO_MINT).transact()
result = w3.eth.waitForTransactionReceipt(tx_hash_dai)
balance_dai = DAI.functions.balanceOf(backend_address).call() / 1e18
print('To wallet %s was been charged %s DAI tokens' % (backend_address, balance_dai))
print('Mint DAI was SUCCESS !')


#  ----------- Mint MY Token -------------------

print('Mint MY Token')
MY_TOKENS_TO_MINT = 7000 * 10 ** 8

with open(os.path.join(ARTIFACTS_PATH, TOKEN_NAME + '.json')) as f:
    swg_interface = json.loads(f.read())

token = w3.eth.contract(abi=swg_interface['abi'], address=addresses[TOKEN_NAME])
tx = token.functions.mint(backend_address, MY_TOKENS_TO_MINT).buildTransaction({
    'gasPrice': w3.eth.gasPrice,
    'nonce': w3.eth.getTransactionCount(backend_address, 'latest'),
    'from': backend_address
})

tx_signed = w3.eth.account.signTransaction(tx, os.environ['BACKEND_PRIVATE_KEY'])
tx_hash_my = w3.eth.sendRawTransaction(tx_signed.rawTransaction)
balance_my = token.functions.balanceOf(backend_address).call() / 1e8
print('To wallet %s was been charged %s MY tokens' % (backend_address, balance_MY))
print('Mint MY was SUCCESS !')


#  ----------- Mint MY Token to KEEPER -------------------

print('Mint MY Token to KEEPER')
keeper_addr = addresses[KEEPER_NAME]
MY_TOKENS_TO_KEEPER = 10000 * 10 ** 8

tx = token.functions.mint(addresses[KEEPER_NAME], MY_TOKENS_TO_MINT).buildTransaction({
    'gasPrice': w3.eth.gasPrice,
    'nonce': w3.eth.getTransactionCount(backend_address, 'latest'),
    'from': backend_address
})

tx_signed_keeper = w3.eth.account.signTransaction(tx, os.environ['BACKEND_PRIVATE_KEY'])
tx_hash_keeper = w3.eth.sendRawTransaction(tx_signed_keeper.rawTransaction)
balance_keeper = token.functions.balanceOf(keeper_addr).call() / 1e8
print('To Keeper Wallet %s was been charged %s MY tokens' % (keeper_addr, balance_keeper))
print('Mint to Keeper Wallet was SUCCESS !')
print('Mint for ALL Tokens was completed successful')
```

"KEEPER" it's additional contract for one of my cases. You can ignore him in code.
It's working now:

[image]